# UICollectionViewCell not forcing Cell Size

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I am using

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 400, height: 600)
}
```

to specify my `CollectionView`'s cell sizes. It works fine but as soon as I add a width constraint `(UILabel.width == ContentView.width)` to my `UILabel` inside the `ContentView` of the cell, the cell's width shrinks to the intrinsic width of the `UILabel`.

I am using `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and horizontal scrolling.

How can I force the `ContentView` to stick to the cell size I specified and let the subviews follow the auto layout constraints?

Comment: If you cell width is 400 then minus padding of both side of uilabel and set it direct instead of only adding left right constraint

Comment: My cell size is actually going to be calculated based upon screen size so can't do it your way.

Comment: But you write return CGSize(width: 400, height: 600) it means your all cell size should be this.

Comment: Yes, cell should be 400x600 but it is not when I add size constraints on UILabel.

Comment: There is two for if cell size is dynamic first you need to get intrinsicContentSize of that label and second one is write your flowLayout and return respective size from this method

Comment: Can you please show some graphics for both cases?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that in the storyboard your collection view's Estimate Size is configured to Automatic:

[image]

You need to set it to None if you want your `sizeForItemAt` implementation to be obeyed rather than the internal constraints.

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly the problem.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.